# Saving and applying states with NGRX

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

So I am learning NGRX and I am close to understanding how it works, I am dispatching events and I can see them in `store-devtools` chrome extension.

What I want to know is how can I save a state and apply it after? My purpose is to save a state from a specific page so that when I'm back to that page I will apply the old state and I will not lose my work there

Here's my repo: https://bitbucket.org/wmoreiradev/ngrxonfire/src/effects-refactor/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like bellow

Create **actions** to save and load current state.

Save the current state before leaving the page. You can do this inside the **reducer** function or inside a **effect** like bellow

```
localStorage.setItem("currentState", JSON.strigify(state));
```

When you load the page **dispatch** an action to load the saved state inside a reducer

```
case Actions.LOAD_SAVED_STATE:
  return {...state, ...action.payload};
```

also, remove the save state from localStorage.

Comment: thank you! but which kind of action do I assign to it? if you look at my post.actions.ts, the actions are receiving strings, so this one would be `export const LOAD_SAVED_STATE = 'Load Saved State';` does that work?

Comment: Is it possible to save the effect save state into a file of json? New to NgRx.

Comment: In browser you can’t access the file apis directly to save a file.

Comment: @Ajantha Bandara: Is saving to local storage the right way ? Is it then safe to save to local storage ? there should be some other way where to save with Ngrx no ?

Comment: it depends on what kind of data you save. saving critical data in local storage not a good thing to do.